# Как сделать PopUp (модальное окно) чтобы оно срабатывало только по нажатию мыши?

Tags: javascript

Нашел в интернете как сделать модальное окно. Код рабочий, но только есть один нюанс, модальное окно срабатывает когда пользователь заходит на сайт.

А как сделать чтобы оно срабатывало только по нажатию мыши?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    PopUpHide();
});
function PopUpShow(){
    $("#popup1").show();
}
function PopUpHide(){
    $("#popup1").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-container">
    Sample Text
    <a href="javascript:PopUpShow()">Show popup</a>
</div>
<div class="b-popup" id="popup1">
    <div class="b-popup-content">
        Text in Popup
    <a href="javascript:PopUpHide()">Hide popup</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так:

```js
function PopUpShow(){
    $("#popup1").show();
    return false;
}
function PopUpHide(){
    $("#popup1").hide();
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-container">
    Sample Text
    <a href="#" onclick="return PopUpShow();">Show popup</a>
</div>
<div class="b-popup" id="popup1" style="display:none;">
    <div class="b-popup-content">
        Text in Popup
    <a href="#" onclick="return PopUpHide();">Hide popup</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Если вы используете бутстрап, то можно вместо инлайн стиля `display: none` использовать класс `d-none`.